# Output "Hello, World!" in the clipboard

Tags: code-golf, hello-world

Make a program (or a function) that copies the exact text "Hello, World!" to the clipboard, and terminates.

Comment: It is not a duplicate. Copying to the clipboard != Delete clipboard contents ! @Phoenix, @ DJMcMayhem

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 19 bytes

Run in your browser's console.

```
copy`Hello, World!`
```

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematica, 31 bytes

```
CopyToClipboard@"Hello, World!"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Notepad++, 15 keystrokes

```
Hello, World!<C-a><C-c>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Windows command shell, 23 characters

```
echo Hello, World!|clip
```